# T\F: If $(t_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of reals s.t $\lim_{k\to\infty}t_ka_k = 0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}t_k|a_{k+1}-a_k|$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a monotonic sequence and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$.
> If $(t_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of reals s.t $\lim_{k\to\infty}t_ka_k = 0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}t_k|a_{k+1}-a_k|$ converges.

I know that for such $(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k+1}-a_k|$ is indeed finite (as a special case of a Cauchy sequence that is monotonic). 
Now I'm interested to know if the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}t_k|a_{k+1}-a_k|$ still holds. Since I couldn't come up with a counter-example and it seems intuitively true to me I tried to use Abel's summation method in order to prove it, however, it doesn't seem to help. I struggle to come up with another idea to approach it and therefore I'm afraid I don't have the knowledge to determine the answer of this question.

I'd be glad to have some new observations\ideas. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_k=2^{-k}$ and $t_k=2^k k^{-1}.$ Then $t_ka_k\to 0$ but $$t_k(a_{k}-a_{k+1})={1\over 2k}$$